# Reading path in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

is there any way to read the path to the current page? For example, I am at www.example.com/foo/bar/ - and I want to read '/foo/bar/'. I have to do this in the template file without modifying views, and I have too many view files to edit each one.

Cheers.

Comment: How has this question been asked before, when the duplicate is from May 2010, and this question is from January 2010? What was first there?

Answer (score 3):

If you add `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting, it will add the `request` variable to every template-rendering that uses a `RequestContext` (which is most of the built-in ones). This is the `HTTPRequest` object for the current request, the `path` attribute of which is the requested path. More information can be found [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request).

Answer (score 2):

[`request.path`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this but ran into a little hiccup along the way. Here's my solution path in the hopes that I save someone else some time.

At first I added this line to my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.core.context_processors.request",)
```

I found that it allowed me to access the request path from within a template which had been passed a `RequestContext` by using the template variable `{{ request.path }}`. However, it also disabled all the other context processors. To fix this I tried adding the defaults to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` tuple. At first this failed because I had used the context processors for Django 1.2 (I have Django 1.1 installed). After fixing that problem I was left with the following settings file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.core.context_processors.auth",
 "django.core.context_processors.debug",
 "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
 "django.core.context_processors.media",
 "django.core.context_processors.request",
 )
```