# How to get the current URL within a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I was wondering how to get the current URL within a template.

Say my current URL is:

```
.../user/profile/
```

How do I return this to the template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading path in templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127937/reading-path-in-templates)

Comment: All the below answers made me think I needed to do some gymnastics to get access to `request` in a template.  In Django 1.10 I just access `{{request.path}}` in the template and it works. By default `django.core.context_processors.request` is already configured in settings.py if you used `startproject`

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Django 1.9 and above:

```
## template
{{ request.path }}  #  -without GET parameters 
{{ request.get_full_path }}  # - with GET parameters
```

Old:

```
## settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

## views.py
from django.template import *

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

## template
{{ request.path }}
```

Comment: A bit laconic, and not correct. It's `render_to_response`, and not `render_to_request`. And you can't define `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` as you do in settings.py, without mentioning the other default processors that may well be used in the templates!

Comment: As of 2016, you no longer need to add anything to views.py. As long as django.core.context_processors.request is loaded in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS - you have access to {{ request.path }} from the template.

Comment: `request.path` does not include query parameters like `?foo=bar`. Use `request.get_full_path` instead.

Comment: @Routhinator agree with you. but it's nice to know that those middleware needs to be included to make this happen.

Comment: As commented in other answers by @Quentin and @user you should include `urlencode` if you plan to use it in a link, typically: `.../accounts/login?next={{ request.get_full_path | urlencode }}...`

Answer (score 305):

You can fetch the URL in your template like this:

```
<p>URL of this page: {{ request.get_full_path }}</p>
```

or by

`{{ request.path }}` if you don't need the extra parameters.

Some precisions and corrections should be brought to [hypete's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432018/183575) and [Igancio's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2882511/183575) answers, I'll just summarize the whole idea here, for future reference.

If you need the `request` variable in the template, you **must** add the 'django.core.context_processors.request' to the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) settings, it's not by default (Django 1.4).

You must also **not forget** the other context processors used by your applications. So, to add the request to the other default processors, you could add this in your settings, to avoid hard-coding the default processor list (that may very well change in later versions):

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Then, provided you [send the `request` contents in your response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), for example as this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'user/profile.html',
        { 'title': 'User profile' },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: I used an extended generic class view, and it was unnecessary to add `request` to the context.

Comment: Definitely cleaner to avoid hard coding the TCP list, but docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#default-settings
 says : `Note that a settings file should not import from global_settings, because that’s redundant`

Comment: `return render(request, 'user/profile.html', {'title': 'User profile'})` is shorter

Comment: remember to include urlencode i.e. `{{request.get_full_path|urlenode}}` if you are redirecting

Comment: how to get parameters from get_full_path ??

Comment: @user Why do we need to use `urlenode`? If I use it like this:   `request.build_absolute_uri|urlencode`, I get this:   `http://127.0.0.1:8000/2020/8/8/http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A8000/2020/8/8/just-a-test-post`  and without it I get normal  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/2020/8/8/just-a-test-post`

Comment: Indeed, I see no need to use `urlencode` (it is `urlencode`, not `urlenode`) since this is already an URL. It would escape characters that mustn't be.

Answer (score 44):

The below code helps me:

```
 {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}
```

Comment: This is useful, as it includes hostname/domain as well.

Comment: and that is the required one for complete path or link

Answer (score 19):

Both `{{ request.path }} and {{ request.get_full_path }}` return the current URL but not absolute URL, for example:

> your_website.com/wallpapers/new_wallpaper
>
> Both will return `/new_wallpaper/`
> (notice the leading and trailing slashes)

So you'll have to do something like

```
{% if request.path == '/new_wallpaper/' %}
    <button>show this button only if url is new_wallpaper</button>
{% endif %}
```

However, you can get the absolute URL using (thanks to the answer above)

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}
```

NOTE:
you don't have to include `requests` in `settings.py`, it's already there.

Answer (score 6):

In django template 
Simply get current url from `{{request.path}}`
For getting full url  with parameters `{{request.get_full_path}}`

**Note**:
You must add `request` in django `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Answer (score 6):

I suppose send to template full request is little bit redundant. I do it this way

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    app_url = request.path
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'app_url': app_url})

##template
{{ app_url }}
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers were incorrect, at least in my case. `request.path` does not provide the full url, only the relative url, e.g. `/paper/53`. I did not find any proper solution, so I ended up hardcoding the constant part of the url in the View before concatenating it with `request.path`.

Comment: Look at the date. The answers were given 6 or 7 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

For Django > 3
I do not change settings or anything.
I add the below code in the template file.

```
{{ request.path }}  #  -without GET parameters 
{{ request.get_full_path }}  # - with GET parameters
```

and in *view.py* pass *request* variable to the template file.

view.py:

```
def view_node_taxon(request, cid):
    showone = get_object_or_404(models.taxon, id = cid)
    context = {'showone':showone,'request':request}
    mytemplate  = loader.get_template('taxon/node.html')
    html = mytemplate.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the url without parameters by using  **{{request.path}}** 
You can get the url with parameters by using  **{{request.get_full_path}}**

Answer (score 3):

if you are using render partial it's better to use

`{{ request.path_info }}`

It returns the exact url of the page

Comment: How can this be coded in python code? I need the url inside a PDF, not html

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it can be summed up as easily as this if you're using django-registration.

In your Log In and Log Out link (lets say in your page header) add the next parameter to the link which will go to login or logout.  Your link should look like this.

```
<li><a href="http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/login/?next={{ request.path | urlencode }}">Log In</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/logout/?next={{ request.path | urlencode }}">Log Out</a></li>
```

That's simply it, nothing else needs to be done, upon logout they will immediately be redirected to the page they are at, for log in, they will fill out the form and it will then redirect to the page that they were on.  Even if they incorrectly try to log in it still works.

Comment: you should encode the path if it is in a url: `{{ request.path|urlencode }}`

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct and they give great and short answer.

I was also looking for getting the current page's url in Django template as my intention was to activate `HOME page`, `MEMBERS page`, `CONTACT page`, `ALL POSTS page` when they are requested.

I am pasting the part of the HTML code snippet that you can see below to understand the use of `request.path`. You can see it in my `live website` at http://pmtboyshostelraipur.pythonanywhere.com/

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!--HOME-->
        {% if "/" == request.path %}
      <li class="active text-center">
          <a href="/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Home" data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="text-center">
          <a href="/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Home" data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      <!--MEMBERS-->
      {% if "/members/" == request.path %}
      <li class="active text-center">
        <a href="/members/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Members"  data-placement="bottom">
          <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="text-center">
        <a href="/members/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Members"  data-placement="bottom">
          <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      <!--CONTACT-->
      {% if "/contact/" == request.path %}
      <li class="active text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contact"  data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contact"  data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      <!--ALL POSTS-->
      {% if "/posts/" == request.path %}
      <li class="text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/posts/"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="All posts"  data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="text-center">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/posts/"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="All posts"  data-placement="bottom">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" style="font-size:25px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: A small suggestion -- if all you are doing is checking whether to add the `active` class to each `li` element, why not just do that inline within one `li` element: `<li class="{% if "/contact/" == request.path %}active {% endif %}text-center">....</li>` instead of a giant if/else block for the whole `li`? That would save a whole bunch of redundant code :)

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3, you want to use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url)  template tag:

```
{% url 'name-of-your-user-profile-url' possible_context_variable_parameter %}
```

For an example, [see the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use example:

```
 <!-- BRAND -->
        <div class="brand">
            <div class="logo">
                {% if request.get_full_path == '/' %}
                    <a href="{% url 'front:homepage' %}" class="first-logo big-logo">
                        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/logo-big.svg' %}"
                             alt="pozitiv">
                    </a>

                    <a href="{% url 'front:homepage' %}" class="second-logo mobile-logo">
                        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/logo.svg' %}"
                             alt="<?php echo WEBSITE_NAME; ?>" >
                    </a>

                {% else %}

                    <a href="{% url 'front:homepage' %}">
                        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/logo.svg' %}"
                             alt="<?php echo WEBSITE_NAME; ?>" style="width: 320px; margin: -20px 0 0 0;">
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the get parameter to template,
you can pass it via `views.py` file

Example:

```
return render(request, 'test.html',{'get_parameter_name' : get_parameter_value})
```

And use in template like:

```
{{get_parameter_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using js in the template as well, you can do this:
In you js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ...
    getUrl();
}

function getUrl() {
    let someDiv = document.querySelector(`#someDiv`);
    someDiv.innerHTML = window.location.href;
}
```

for your template

```
...
<div id="someDiv"><div>
...
```