# How do I find the path of the url inside a django template?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the current URL within a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template)

For example I would like something like this inside the template:

```
            {% if path == 'login' %}
                <li class="current_page_item"> <a href="{% url login-view %}"> {{ 'Login' }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li> <a href="{% url login-view %}"> {{ 'Login' }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[request.get_full_path](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path)

Comment: Thank you, I decided to make it into a context processor.