# How to add the current query string to an URL in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

When I load a page, there is a link *"sameLink"* that I want to append to it the ***query string*** of its containing page.

I have following URL:

```
somedomain/reporting/article-by-month?variable1=2008
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you read this?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#example  It seems very clear how you capture parts of a URL.  What's your question?

Comment: I want to get query part of current URL and add it to a link from that page. This must be done in template.

Comment: @Nerses: Please **update** the question to explain **completely** what you are trying to do.  Include code samples if possible, even if they don't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template

Comment: Why -1 ??? i think you should not give -1 !

Answer (score 130, accepted):

To capture the QUERY_PARAMS that were part of the request, you reference the dict that contains those parameters (`request.GET`) and urlencode them so they are acceptable as part of an href.  `request.GET.urlencode` returns a string that looks like `ds=&date_published__year=2008` which you can put into a link on the page like so:

```
<a href="sameLink/?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">
```

Comment: For those just getting started, make sure you have the django.core.context_processors.request context processor enabled in your settings.

Comment: It's `django.template.context_processors.request` in later django versions, but anyway the above didn't work for me, returns empty string

Comment: @stelios I just faced the same problem and fixed it. You just need to pass `request` object to your template

Comment: I think the intention is to use the `urlencode`  (pipe not dot) `<a href="sameLink/?{{ request.GET.variable1|urlencode }}">`

Answer (score 24):

If you register a templatetag like follows:

```
@register.simple_tag
def query_transform(request, **kwargs):
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    updated.update(kwargs)
    return updated.urlencode()
```

you can modify the query string in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'view_name' %}?{% query_transform request a=5 b=6 %}">
```

This will preserve anything already in the query string and just update the keys that you specify.

Comment: This and @Prydie's answer deserve more attention. I have an use case with filtering, sorting and pagination and without this idea I would be screwed. I see that use case as very common indeed.

Comment: Note the `update()` in this case "... appends to the current dictionary items rather than replacing them.". See [QueryDict docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.update)

Answer (score 22):

I found that @Michael's answer didn't quite work when you wanted to update an existing query parameter.

The following worked for me:

```
@register.simple_tag
def query_transform(request, **kwargs):
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        updated[k] = v

    return updated.urlencode()
```

Comment: Here is the reason why `update()` function didn't quite work: **"Just like the standard dictionary update() method, except it appends to the current dictionary items rather than replacing them."** Refer to documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Answer (score 7):

Following on from @Prydie (thank you!) I wanted to do the same, but in Python 3 & Django 1.10, with the addition of being able to strip querystring keys as well as modify them. To that end, I use this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def query_transform(request, **kwargs):
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v is not None:
            updated[k] = v
        else:
            updated.pop(k, 0)  # Remove or return 0 - aka, delete safely this key

    return updated.urlencode()
```

The python 3 bit being `kwargs.items()` over `.iteritems()`

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Prydie's solution (which itself uses @Michael's), I constructed the tag to return the complete URL instead of just the parameter string.

My **myproject/template_tags.py**

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/24658162/2689986
@register.simple_tag
def add_query_params(request, **kwargs):
    """
    Takes a request and generates URL with given kwargs as query parameters
    e.g.
    1. {% add_query_params request key=value %} with request.path=='/ask/'
        => '/ask/?key=value'
    2. {% add_query_params request page=2 %} with request.path=='/ask/?key=value'
        => '/ask/?key=value&page=2'
    3. {% add_query_params request page=5 %} with request.path=='/ask/?page=2'
        => '/ask/?page=5'
    """
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        updated[k] = v

    return request.build_absolute_uri('?'+updated.urlencode())
```

My **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...
            # loads custom template tags
            'libraries': {
                'mytags': 'config.template_tags',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

**Sample usage** in templates:

```
{% load mytags %}
<a href="{% add_query_params request page=2 %}">
```

Tested with Python3.6 in Django1.11.10

Answer (score 5):

Informed by other answers but not needing the `request` passed in and only updates existing parameters.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def querystring(context, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates a URL (containing only the querystring [including "?"]) derived
    from the current URL's querystring, by updating it with the provided
    keyword arguments.

    Example (imagine URL is ``/abc/?gender=male&name=Tim``)::

        {% querystring "name"="Diego" "age"=20 %}
        ?name=Diego&gender=male&age=20
    """
    request = context['request']
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():  # have to iterate over and not use .update as it's a QueryDict not a dict
        updated[k] = v

    return '?{}'.format(updated.urlencode()) if updated else ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround if you don't want loops or string concatenations.

String representation of url is something like `'<WSGIRequest: GET \'our_url\'>'`
So if you want `our_url`, you just need to use regex for it.

```
our_url = re.search(r'\/.*(?=\'>)', str(request)).group()
```