# Combine GET variables using links

Tags: python, html, django

I have a view that will show some products. Also I have a filter on the left side.

For example:

Price: Less than $5, $5 - $10 ... etc.
Brand: Apple, IBM, Intel etc.

the problem with the links now.

```
 <a href="?brand=IBM">IBM</a>

 <a href="?price=0|5">From 0 to $5</a>
```

Now I need these queries to be combined together. However, each link will remove the other queries.

Expected Result:

```
  ?brand=IBM&price=0|5
```

I know I can do it using many if else. But is there anyway to do it in django or HTML to make this happen?

Another Explanation:

*I need a way that will keep adding to the query in the URL. like amazon when you filter the products. First you pick the brand then you pick the price range then etc. I don't want to check every time if there is a query in the Url or not. I just want a way that will not remove the current query and just keep adding to it.*

Comment: Which link would you click in order to get both?  Or does clicking a link add onto the URL?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to do this by passing parameters to your urls?

Comment: Look at the [`urllib.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) module (just [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) in Python 2.x). It shows you how to parse a query string. Then you probably want to use some HTML library like `BeautifulSoup` to build a new `a` node for the combined result.

Comment: @Xero I need a way that will keep adding to the query in the URL. like amazon when filter the products. First you pick the brand then you pick the price range then etc. I don't want to check everytime if there is a query in the Url or not. I just want a way that will not remove the current query and just keep adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following template tag should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135527/176186.

You might also think about using a proven app like [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).