Filters and Pagination with Django Function-Based Views
I'm working on my first Django program and would like to create a template including filtering and pagination functions that could be used simultaneously. This is what I have so far:
models.py
class Player (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.surname}"
            
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Players"

views.py
def GetPlayers(request):
    players = Player.objects.all().values()
    
    pn = request.GET.get('name')
    if pn != '' and pn is not None:
        players = players.filter(name__icontains=pn)

    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(players, 2)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    
    template = loader.get_template('players.html')
    context = {
        'players' : players,
        'page_obj' : page_obj,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

players.html
{% block content %}
  <div class="mycard">
    <h1>Players</h1>
    <div class="filters">
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-3">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="name" {% if name %} value = "{{ name }}" {% endif %}>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-2" style="padding-top: 2%;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn custom-btn">Filter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p/>
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for x in page_obj %}
            <td>{{ x.name }}</td>          
            <td>{{ x.surname }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {% include "pagination.html" %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

Let's imagine I have 6 players called "John", "Mark", "Phil", "Jason", "Jane" and "Juliet". If I don't apply any name filtering, they will be grouped as follows:

Page 1: "John" and "Mark"
Page 2: "Phil" and "Jason"
Page 3: "Jane" and "Juliet"

Based on this, if I filter by names containing "J" in the filter text field, I would expect to have:

Page 1: "John" and "Jason"
Page 2: "Jane" and "Juliet"

Page 1 works as intended, but when I click on the link to navigate to page 2, the filter seems to be reset and I got "Phil" and "Jason"; besides, a link to the third page becomes available, including "Jane and Juliet"  as if there was no filter applied at all.
How could I keep filters applied while navigating through the queryset pages?

You didn't post your pagination.html, but I'll assume you're using the "standard" pagination. If so, maybe this answer is what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135527/20133673
It's a template tag that allows you to capture the query parameters and preserve it when you change pages.

are you sure request.GET include name in page 2?

You need to append your filter as a query param to the pagination URL. For that it is necessary to have it inside the context.
views.py
(a minor change to shorten and make it a bit more clean)
def GetPlayers(request):
    players = Player.objects.all().values()

    pn = request.GET.get("name", None)
    if pn:
        players = players.filter(name__icontains=pn)

    paginator = Paginator(players, 2)
    page_num = request.GET.get("page")
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    ctx = {"players": players, "page_obj": page_obj, "pn": pn}
    return render(request, "players.html", ctx)

pagination.html
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page=1{% if pn %}&name={{pn}}{% endif %}">&laquo; first</a>
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if pn %}&name={{pn}}{% endif %}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
      Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% if pn %}&name={{pn}}{% endif %}">next</a>
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}{% if pn %}&name={{pn}}{% endif %}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
  </span>
</div>

Note: As a good practice (name convention), functions and variables are often named in snake_case
