# Django template, if tag based on current URL value

Tags: django

I want to be able to do an if tag based on the current URL value.

for example, if the current page's url is `accounts/login/` then don't show a link, without passing a variable from the view.

I am not sure how I can write an `{% if %}` tag for this, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you pass the "request" object to your template, then you are able to use this:

```
{% if request.get_full_path == "/account/login/" %}
```

Comment: There is a very small typo in this that I can't update with an edit. You need to use == not = for the comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying to solve this issue for a 1-hour thanks a lot

Answer (score 69):

You can also do this for dynamic urls using:

```
{% url 'show_user_page' user=user as the_url %}
{% if request.get_full_path == the_url %}something{% endif %}
```

where your urls.py contains something like:

```
(r'^myapp/user/(?P<user>\d+)/$', 'show_user_page'),
```

I know this because I just spent ages drafting a stackoverflow question, when I found [the answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in the docs.

I'd say even in simple cases this might be the better approach, because it is more loosely coupled.

Comment: Woooow. the `as` there made my day. Using same snippet over multiple pages via include tag, and needed a way to display different links depending on what page on. Priceless approach!

Comment: Thank you I really thought it would be harder than this. the url alias is useful because I wasn't sure how to compare the full path to just a root index page which has nothing discernable in the path to compare for

Comment: Also make sure that `user` is in the `context` given to the template.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic urls, you can also use the `request.resolver_match` attribute ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match)):

> `HttpRequest.resolver_match`
>
> An instance of ResolverMatch representing the resolved URL. This attribute is only set after URL resolving took place, which means it’s available in all views but not in middleware which are executed before URL resolving takes place (you can use it in process_view() though).

The returned `ResolverMatch` object has many useful attributes, such as the `view_name` attribute, which returns the same name you would have passed to the `url` templatetag to generate the current url.

> `view_name`
>
> The name of the view that matches the URL, including the namespace if there is one.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) for this and other attributes.

Applying this to the example from @nimasmi's answer, you would get:

```
{% if request.resolver_match.view_name == 'show_user_page' %}something{% endif %}
```

where your urls.py contains something like:

```
(r'^myapp/user/(?P<user>\d+)/$', 'show_user_page'),
```

Note that when you use [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces), `view_name` will return the namespace qualified url/view name, e.g. `app:urlname`.

Compared to the answer by @nimasmi, this simplifies the template code a bit, by not needing the separate `{% url %}` tag to generate the url to compare with. This is especially true when you do not need to compare view parameters, just the view name. If you do need to compare parameters in the url, you can easily use the [`ResolverMatch.args`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.args) and [`kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.kwargs) attributes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?
`if "order" in request.path`
Using "in" allows you to match URLs like:
customers, customer, customer/new, customer/edit, etc

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link

<pre>{% if "order" in request.path %} active {% endif %} "</pre>

                        href="/orders">Order List</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link

<pre>{% if "customer" in request.path %} active {% endif %} "</pre>

                        href="/customers">Customer List</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link

<pre>{% if "product" in request.path %} active {% endif %} "</pre>

                       href="/products">Product List</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
```