# django check within template if the current url has a particular word in it

Tags: django

Similar to this question:

[Django template, if tag based on current URL value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7462398/1061426)

only I want to check if the url has a word in it - you know, like

```
if a.find(b) == -1
```

how can i do this?

Comment: downvoters - a comment about the question, perchance?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Perhaps the `in` operator?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator)

```
{% if b in request.path %}
    hello world!
{% endif %}
```

If that doesn't accomplish what you need then move the logic to your view or create a [custom template tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: to clarify: for this to work, you have to make sure to pass the request object to the template

Comment: Note this doesn't search the GET parameters in the url

Answer (score 2):

Forget `request` parameters and use:

```
{% if 'search_term' in request.GET %}
  Hello World!
{% endif %}
```