# add class active to li in django templates

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

Base.html

```
<ul class="" id="main-menu" style="">


<li class="root-level has-sub activeroot-level cbs0">
        <a href="#" class=""><i class="entypo-globe "></i><span>CBS</span></a>


    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs1/" class="cbs1"><i class="entypo-lamp "></i><span>Initiative and Decision Making</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs2/"><i class="entypo-publish cbs2"></i><span>Analyzing And Problem Solving</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs3/"><i class="entypo-search"></i><span>Customer Focus</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs4/"><i class="entypo-bookmarks"></i><span>Achieve Business Results</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs5/"><i class="entypo-feather"></i><span>Flexibility</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs6/"><i class="entypo-shuffle"></i><span>Leading & Engaging</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs7/"><i class="entypo-users"></i><span>Teamwork</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/cbs8/"><i class="entypo-sound"></i><span>Communication</span></a>
        </li>

        </ul>

</li>

<li class="root-level has-sub std0">
        <a href="#"><i class="entypo-globe "></i><span>SELECT STANDARD WORKS</span></a>


    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw1/"><i class="entypo-lamp"></i><span>Initiative and Decision Making</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw2/"><i class="entypo-publish"></i><span>Analyzing And Problem Solving</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw3/"><i class="entypo-search"></i><span>Customer Focus</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw4/"><i class="entypo-bookmarks"></i><span>Achieve Business Results</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw5/"><i class="entypo-feather"></i><span>Flexibility</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw6/"><i class="entypo-shuffle"></i><span>Leading & Engaging</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw7/"><i class="entypo-users"></i><span>Teamwork</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/cbs/sw8/"><i class="entypo-sound"></i><span>Communication</span></a>
        </li>

        </ul>

</li>
</ul>
```

i want add css class active to li when its in particular page 
all other templates associated with the url are extending from the base.html

if i am clicking on Initiative and Decision Making link of SELECT STANDARD WORKS then that active class should get added to SELECT STANDARD WORKS li

I tried using jquery, but may be because of page getting reloaded class is not getting added to li.

These all menu i.e li are in base files and iam extending it other templaetes. So on which li i clicked that should get active.

Guide me please

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462398/django-template-if-tag-based-on-current-url-value