# Can a django template find out its named url or can a base template know which template is extending it?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my URLConf, I have my URLs neatly named so I can do reverse lookups and keep everything DRY.

All my templates extend a universal template named `base.html`. In `base.html`, amongst a lot of HTML framework, I display a login form.

I also have a specific view which uses Django's provided `auth_views.login` view, which displays my custom template `login.html`. This template, like all others, extend the base.html template.

In cases like this, I would like that the `base.html` template would not display its login form (the `login.html` template already is displaying a login form). In order to do this, `base.html` either needs to know that it is being used to extend `login.html`, or, know that the named URL which resulted in base.html being extended is has the name `'myapp-login'`.

Can you suggest a way to do this? I am thinking of writing my own view which will call `auth_views.login` with extra context which includes a `suppress_header_login_form` var. Based on this var, the `base.html` template could suppress the login form. However, I am trying to see if there is a nicer way to accomplish this.

Comment: Maybe this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template

Comment: Very close. However, my problem is that this particular template is called from TemplateView. In such a case, the request is not passed to the template, and there is no way to get the URL through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could manage this with template inheritance and blocks.

Your `base.html` defines a block called `login`, which surrounds the HTML for the login - and your `login.html` overrides that block with an empty version:

base.html:

```
{% block login %}
    ... login form here ...
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
{% endblock %}
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block login %}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
   ... real login form here ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Haven't thought of this. Nice suggestion. Solves the issue. I will leave this open for a bit more, as I am curious if there is a way to actually check what I mentioned in the original post.