# how to get slug of current url in current template

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django template, How to get the slug of the URL I am on in the template so that I can pass it to the template tag.

Example  I am on: foo.com/slugname

then in the template, I am expecting

```
{% function|slugname%}
```

where 'function' is my template tag.

Comment: {{ request.path }}
{{ request.get_full_path }}

Comment: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/20/django-tip-7-how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your urlpattern for the view is something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<slug>", views.SomeView.as_view(), name="some_name"),
]
```

you can get the slug's value to use in your template using `request.resolver_match.kwargs.slug`.

See also Django documentation on the [HttpRequest objects](http://django.template.context_processors.request) and the [ResolverMatch class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch).

Comment: Thank you.It work properly ({% if request.resolver_match.kwargs.slug == 'slog_name'%} active {% endif %})