# Django - Would I be able to use template tags for rendering HTML given URL path conditionals?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail

I have a blog page with the path `/articles/`. I would like to use conditional statements to reflect HTML renders.

For example, my blog uses a paginator for blog posts. The paginator uses a URL query to retrieve the next page of post objects like so: `/articles/?page=2`

I would like for the next page to stylize the HTML template differently, hence my reasoning for using a conditional statement.

Here is my template that I use:

```py
{% if request.path == '/articles/' %}
# Render HTML only meant for the above path



{% elif request.path != '/articles/'%} 
# Render HTML for paths that are NOT the exact match above, such as pagination URLs, 
# search querys, categories filtering, etc...

{% endif %}
```

My current bug is that I'm only rendering the first statement: `if request.path == '/articles/'` for everything, even non exact matches.

So this URL path: `/articles/?page=2` is rendering: `{% if request.path == '/articles/' %}` when it should be rendering the elif `{% elif request.path != '/articles/'%}`  due to the not equals sign.

Is the above possible to do with only HTML template tags? I know I can use urls.py and edit views but I'm using wagtail CMS and playing with the template seems like the most easiest thing to do right now.

Comment: I think this answer can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432018/9435709

Answer (score 1):

`request.path` [does not include the '?...' querystring part of the URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path), so this is working as designed - the path portion of the URL `/articles/?page=2` *is* `/articles/`.

Django compiles the querystring into the dictionary `request.GET`, so one way of doing what you want is to check whether that dictionary is empty or not:

```
{% if not request.GET %}
    request is for the plain URL /articles/
{% else %}
    request has a querystring parameter on it
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much, this is a smart way of doing it. My only worry is that the conditional seems very broad. Any caveats to worry about?

Comment: It does not seem to work for every case, for example , this query: /articles/tag/model/, so I ended up using the first answer given from Mohammad comment.