# How to get URL of current page, including parameters, in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-request

Is there a way to get the current page URL and all its parameters in a Django template?

For example, a templatetag that would print a full URL like `/foo/bar?param=1&baz=2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading path in templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127937/reading-path-in-templates)

Comment: another possible duplicate is [Get the current URL withing a Django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Write a custom context processor. e.g.

```
def get_current_path(request):
    return {
       'current_path': request.get_full_path()
     }
```

add a path to that function in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings variable, and use it in your template like so:

```
{{ current_path }}
```

If you want to have the full `request` object in every request, you can use the built-in [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/context_processors.py#L70) context processor, and then use `{{ request.get_full_path }}` in your template.

See:

- [Custom Context Processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)
- [HTTPRequest's get_full_path() method.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path)

Comment: Don't forget to use urlencode i.e. `{{request.get_full_path|urlencode}}` if you need this for redirection

Answer (score 27):

Use Django's build in context processor to get the request in template context. In settings add `request` processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    # Put your context processors here

    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

And in template use:

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}
```

This way you do not need to write any new code by yourself.

Comment: It should be noted that using this method overwrites the default TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS so you will have to add those back to the list.  [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) have a list of the defaults to include in the list.

Comment: It should be noted that in newer versions of Django this settings key has changed to `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']`, and that the aformentioned context processor is included by default.

Answer (score 9):

In a file context_processors.py (or the like):

```
def myurl( request ):
  return { 'myurlx': request.get_full_path() }
```

In settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  ...
  wherever_it_is.context_processors.myurl,
  ...
```

In your template.html:

```
myurl={{myurlx}}
```

Comment: Sorry, downvoted by mistake.. please make a change so that I can undo that.

Answer (score 6):

If we are acessing the following URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/?q=test`

then

```
request.path = '/home/'
request.get_full_path() = '/home/?q=test'
request.build_absolute_uri() = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/?q=test'
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has a lot of built-in stuff, but if you don't explicit what do you want to use, it won't be used.

So, in MTV schema (Model, Template, View) the view receives a request and uses a template render to generate a response, passing on it a dictionary or all local variables (using the locals() function) of this view. Knowing this, we can insert the current url that came from the response, like this:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def page(request):
    currentUrl = request.get_full_path()
    return render(request, 'app/page.html', locals())
```

Then, in the template 'app/page.html' you just have to do the following to display the currentUrl variable that we just created and passed through via locals():

app/template/page.html:

```
{{ currentUrl }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addtition to sdolan's answer:

if you are using I18N and would like to pass `next` value to [`/i18n/setlang/`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) to change the language of the current page, then you will need to strip off current language code from the full path either. Something like:

```
full_path = request.get_full_path()
current_path = full_path[full_path.index('/', 1):]
```

This assumes that every path has format `/LANG_CODE/any/other/stuff/with/?param='yay'` and simply kicks off `LANG_CODE` whatever it is (e.g., `/en/` will result into `/`).

Answer (score 2):

You can see if your url differs from the others.

```
{% if 'foo/bar/' in request.get_full_path %}
```