# Django: get current url path from actual current page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a situation which I hope you can help me.  I have read a few post and answers about getting current url path on SO [current_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template) and  [url TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248682/django-get-url-of-current-page-including-parameters-in-a-template) (which are most relevant).  But it doesn't seem to fit what I am trying to do.  I have a view:

```
def fish_search(request):
    args = {}
    #irrelevant code here
    args['fishes'] = fishes
    args['current_path'] = request.get_full_path()
    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', args)
```

In my ajax_search.html:

```
<a id="search-results" href="{{ current_path }}"></a>
```

And base.html:

```
div id="search-results" ></div>
```

Javascript dumps the search results to base.html.  And base.html is extended in fishMarket.html, fishDictionary.html, fishRumour.html, etc.  So, sadly, the paths that show up are all "/search/"

I want the path to be /fishMarket/ if I am searching from fishMarket.html, /fishDictionary/ should show up if I am searching from fishDictionary.html, and likewise, /fishRumour/ if I am searching from fishRumour.html.  Have anyone come across this type of situation?  How did you solve this problem?  I'm relatively new to django, so please dumb down the solution.

I really appreciate your help. many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `request.get_full_path()`, which will give you path of search view, use referrer from the HTTP headers.

You can get that with `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution.  But I got the following errors when replacing request.get_full_path() with request.META['HTTP_REFERRER'] and the error is KeyError: 'HTTP_REFERRER'
KeyError: 'HTTP_REFERRER'

Comment: `REFERER` is misspelled. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: @vt2424253, sorry the HTTP_REFERRER is mispelled, it should be HTTP_REFERER - with single R

Comment: Thanks!  I was doing some search and that's what I discovered, too.  btw, if you think this question could be useful for others on SO, please up vote the question.  I really appreciate your help.