# how to make request.get_full_path() to work for uploading files in django 1.8

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

This is related issue, (nothingisnecessary) suggested that request.get_full_path should work for my project, i have tried everything so far and still cannot get it working. Maybe there is someone who would be willing to help 
[Django 1.8 uploading files for a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569174/django-1-8-uploading-files-for-a-specific-location?noredirect=1#comment51258562_31569174)

I just need to be able to upload files to the location which automatically would be created depending on the template.html that would be used at a time.

Desperate at this point ....

thank you

Comment: get_full_path returns part of an URL; please explain what you mean by it to work for uplading files?  Do you wan't to store the uploaded files in a file system path built from the URL path?

Comment: hello, thank you for reply, that is correct. Do you know how this can be dine using model.py the example is in the link in the question. thank you